# Android NetworkOnMainThreadException exception

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I had this Networkonmainthread exception in my activity. I searched for a solution for the problem. While I was searching, I found that I should use `AsyncTask`. After I tried `AsyncTask`, I am still facing the same problem.

This is my register activity:

```
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            if (params.length != 3)
                return null;
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(params[0], params[1], params[2]);
            return json;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                new MyAsyncTask().execute(name, email, password);
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully registred
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);
                            // Close Registration Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // Close Registration View
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my logcat:

```
09-26 00:56:23.865: D/AndroidRuntime(791): Shutting down VM
09-26 00:56:23.875: W/dalvikvm(791): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:45)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at library.UserFunctions.registerUser(UserFunctions.java:62)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.example.bustracker.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:105)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-26 00:56:23.925: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 00:56:24.215: W/System.err(791): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http:// refused
09-26 00:56:24.436: W/System.err(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
09-26 00:56:24.546: W/System.err(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
09-26 00:56:24.786: W/System.err(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
09-26 00:56:24.967: W/System.err(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
09-26 00:56:24.995: W/System.err(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
09-26 00:56:25.017: W/System.err(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-26 00:56:25.017: W/System.err(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
09-26 00:56:25.165: W/System.err(791):  at library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:45)
09-26 00:56:25.235: W/System.err(791):  at library.UserFunctions.registerUser(UserFunctions.java:62)
09-26 00:56:25.264: W/System.err(791):  at com.example.bustracker.RegisterActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:43)
09-26 00:56:25.265: W/System.err(791):  at com.example.bustracker.RegisterActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:1)
09-26 00:56:25.285: W/System.err(791):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-26 00:56:25.305: W/System.err(791):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-26 00:56:25.535: W/System.err(791):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-26 00:56:25.535: W/System.err(791):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-26 00:56:25.675: W/System.err(791):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-26 00:56:25.956: W/System.err(791):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-26 00:56:26.115: W/System.err(791):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-26 00:56:26.147: W/System.err(791): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 8888): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
09-26 00:56:26.226: W/System.err(791):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
09-26 00:56:26.226: W/System.err(791):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
09-26 00:56:26.236: W/System.err(791):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
09-26 00:56:26.236: W/System.err(791):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
09-26 00:56:26.246: W/System.err(791):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
09-26 00:56:26.255: W/System.err(791):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
09-26 00:56:26.255: W/System.err(791):  ... 17 more
09-26 00:56:26.266: W/System.err(791): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
09-26 00:56:26.276: W/System.err(791):  at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
09-26 00:56:26.286: W/System.err(791):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
09-26 00:56:26.286: W/System.err(791):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
09-26 00:56:26.286: W/System.err(791):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
09-26 00:56:26.296: W/System.err(791):  ... 22 more
09-26 00:56:26.296: E/Buffer Error(791): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 00:56:26.305: E/JSON Parser(791): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
09-26 00:56:27.146: I/Process(791): Sending signal. PID: 791 SIG: 9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NetworkOnMainThread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745859/networkonmainthread)

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace says you're calling a network operation in `getJSONFromUrl()` and calling that on the UI thread in `registerUser()`. The code here looks to be the culprit:

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute(name, email, password);
UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);
```

You're first invoking the `registerUser()` in a background asynctask (good!) and then only a couple of lines later doing the same again on the main thread (bad!). Remove the latter.

Comment: Thanks.network issue solved.but now i am getting "http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8888 refused" error

Comment: It's unlikely there's a web server running on your Android device localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I bet userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext()); issues network request to logout user thus error caused by accessing network on main thread (onPostResult runs on ui thread, in contrary to doInBackground)

Answer (score 0):

According to the code in your post, you're still calling userFunction.registerUser directly from inside of the onClickListener handler - right after calling MyAsyncTask.execute. It's that registerUser call that the logcat output is complaining about, not the one in the AsyncTask. Did you mean to delete the duplicate call from the onClickListener handler after you moved that logic to the AsyncTask?